# Sony SDK on computer

Tags: sdk, sony

I would like to use the sony SDK to display image from my SONY alpha 5000 on my computer.
I notice that the supplied  SDK is to develop and Android application. Is there a computer version SDK to be able to connect to the camera with the WIFI and control it?

Comment: Not a programming question directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm also a newbie on the Sony remote camera API SDK. And I started with the same questions as you. Actually the API SDK can be understand as an instruction set that can be used in fairly any platform. This being said, one option is to workarround the programming language that you manage (Python, C, VB....) and send the instruction through a network service (Myself, I have been trying with network sockets on C#). There are some examples on the web, which are ready to go as [Locana](http://locana.github.io/) and [Camera RC](http://www.friedemann-seebass.de/camera_rc_e.html), both of which I have found very useful. If you want to make your app yourself, you can check a bit the code for C I posted on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356310/sony-remote-app-on-c-stucked-after-trying-liveview) (Please do not start with liveview... If you do, and get to do it, let me know). I hope it can be of any help.

Comment: Do you know any cpp example desktop version to control Sony camera?

Comment: @bird12358 I haven't found any. You can give it a try by looking the C# examples. I have been working on [this code](https://github.com/FriedCesar/MIcroscope-control-GIT/tree/BackgroundWorker-added). However it goes beyond only simple control of the camera (I am using it to control a microscope stage with a stepper motor). Please check the main question for the other links.